# Easiest way to create a constant 1V voltage drop

Tags: voltage, led, semiconductors

I need to find a small, cheap, easy way to get a 1V drop in a circuit. It needs to be such that below 1V it acts like an open switch, and above 1V the drop is a constant 1V. Basically an LED without (necessarily) light, except LEDs don't tend to have a forward drop that low - is there any other simple component that will work? I don't really want to have to use a 3-terminal transistor, just to keep it simple.

Comment: Hmm. Silicon diode + Schottky diode in series? How exact do you need it to be, especially at low current?

Comment: A Zener diode would be a very simple way to get a defined voltage drop.

Comment: Joe, this might be much better if you told us what the real problem you are trying to solve is. What does "*It needs to be such that below 1V it's completely off ...*" mean? What needs to be off the 1 V dropper or the circuit after it. Put the info in your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: There's a common device that has 1.25V across its terminals (a bandgap reference) with good accuracy and low temperature sensitivity, whenever 10 uA to 100 mA current is available to bias it.   There's no 1.00V equivalent.

Comment: This question is an optimisation problem, stated without sufficient boundary conditions or the intended application. See: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: What's complicated about a three terminal device?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to find a small, cheap, easy way to get a 1V drop in a circuit.

Try an ADR510 1 volt shunt regulator: -

[image]

They are about £1 in one off quantities and about £0.50 in large quantities.

If you think cheap means less than a penny then you need to be clearer.

Comment: Are you sure that thing turns off below 1V or does it just go into pass-through... I cant see anything on the datasheet to say.

Comment: It's probably no worse or better than an LED (as suggested as a potential solution in the question) - it will gradually take less and less of the 100 uA current until at 0 volts it'll take 0 uA.

Comment: Yup, missing info though, he might be  pulling an amp.. This is a nice device though.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage drop of a LED is related with the wavelength of the photons it emits. To reduce the voltage, increase the wavelength, i.e., use an IR LED.

In practice, IR LEDs are optimized for wavelengths where photodiodes/transistors have their highest sensitivity, so the voltage drop often will be larger than 1 V. Furthermore, the voltage is not very constant if the current changes (here: Everlight IR17-21C/TR8):

[image: Everlight IR17-21C/TR8 Vf vs. If]